# Expired Auth Token for YouTube

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, auth-token

I have read this [http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2.html](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2.html.) 
my problem is I need code in C# .net what will return Expired  Token for Youtube account. But I could not understand what parameters i need use in my link for Get request.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo

access_token =  DQA**********_ONz

may be some idea?

thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the authorization token is valid?  Why do you want code that will return the Expired Token?

Comment: I have looks to it and see that access token is valid and fine and don't have expired period.